# how to set the property of the ViewController before presenting it as presentModalViewController?

Tags: xcode, initialization, uilabel, presentmodalviewcontroller, outlet

I present the view controller like this:

```
FBViewController *fbViewController =[[FBViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FBViewController" bundle:nil];
fbViewController.label.text=@"hello"; // I set the value of the property label which is the outlet
[self presentModalViewController:fbViewController animated:YES];
```

FBViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FBViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

@end
```

FBViewController.m:

```
...
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"%@", self.label.text); // Here instead of "hello" i get the value which was in nib file.

}
...
```

The question is how to set the value of the label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the NSString retrieve text to assign label modalview controller:

```
FBViewController *fbViewController =[[FBViewController alloc]   initWithNibName:@"FBViewController" bundle:nil];
 fbViewController.labeltext=@"Your Text";
 [self presentModalViewController:fbViewController animated:YES];
```

FBViewController.h

```
@interface FBViewController : UIViewController {

 NSString *labeltext;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *labeltext;
```

and use view to load method in FBViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  label1.text=labeltext;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Do you know why my code didn't work? Why can't I set the property of the outlet directly?

Comment: Because Controls are regenerate on Modal View Controller Showing and label text set default Text....!